# call filter date on views global php by defaultviews_handler_filter_date

Tags: views

I use the ['Datex'-module](https://www.drupal.org/project/datex) to use a Persian calendar. I want to call a period of dates in views that is exposed filter. How could I call default handler in views?

More specific:

A user chooses a period of dates, like so:
***1393-11-01* to *1393-11-12***
and in my database these records have the 'Gregorian' format. 'Views'-module by itself changes the format of the Persian date to 'Gregorian' in its query.

I get values, like this:

`$view = views_get_current_view();
$datemin = $view->exposed_input['field_date_value']['min']['datex_edit_field_date_value_min'];`

Now how could I call handler?

OR how could I understand what the 'Views'-module does to change the format of the date by itself, i.e. from Persian to Gregorian?